# Как поставить две версии ActivePython на одну систему?

Tags: python, windows-7, интерпретатор

Конкретно нужно поставить ActivePython 2.7 и 3.0 на Windows 7.
Люди предлагают вызывать нужный интерпретатор командой `python2` и `python3` из `cmd`. А вы как думаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). С помощью [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) можно создать изолированные конфигурации со своими версиями интерпретатора и набором библиотек.

Answer (score 2):

как вариант файлы для python3 сохранять с расширением .py3 и связать его с нужным интерпретатором. Ну или указывать явно при запуске скрипта

```
python3 script.py
```